# Black text on dark background on Nougat (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have some basic piece of code on a Welcome Activity that simply binds List adapter as usual:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

This **used to work until I updated to API level 25**. At that point, with no other changes, the spinner dropdown's text has become un-readable:

[image: black text on dark background android 7]

My theme's parent is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" but again, **I'm not playing with colors** there and nothing changed since when it was showing correctly (API < 25). Any idea?

I know I could fix it with some `setTextColor()` inside `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()`, but the main point is understanding why it was working and now it doesn't, as this may be a sign of something conceptuyally wrong on my side, or even some kind of Android bug. Infact, i noticed the same problem (black text on dark background) on pretty standard widgets/app, like the Cyanogen/LineageOS default weather one:

[image: black text on dark background android 7]

Comment: Let me check, didnt see that you are using the Android spinner item

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I know level 20 is good. both 24 and 25 are bad.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It's working fine on level 20. After upgrading to 25, it has this problem. However, even if I downgrade from level 25 to level 20, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @PokerIncome.com Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
Your color definition may be `android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"`. When I fixed it  as `android:textColor="#FF000000"`, it is working fine. Or you can use     `android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"`.

I heard from my co-working, the first 2 hex meaning is changed. It is changed the SDK version 24.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that at run time when I try to create the spinner the colors are buggy so I made a workaround making a layou with the color I wanted in the text and setting this layout when in dark mode, just making it clear I used the default theme at the beginning of the tests but it also doesn't work and neither what I created and put in the color.xml files worked

```
/* Start Workaround */
int layout = R.layout.simple_spinner_item_black;
if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES){layout = R.layout.simple_spinner_item_white;}
/* End Workaround */
```